# SAS/SQL Question: How do I merge based on a variable in a row to information in the column header?

Tags: sql, sas, dataset, conditional-statements

I am trying to merge two datasets.  One dataset is:

```
Date     Item    Price    Group
1/1/18    Hat      $5        1
2/1/18    Hat      $5        1
1/1/18    Shirt    $10       2
2/1/18    Shirt    $10       2
1/1/18    Shoes    $30       3
2/1/18    Shoes    $30       3
```

The other dataset is:

```
Date        Group1AvgCost    Group2AvgCost      Group3AvgCost
1/1/18           $2                $8                $25
2/1/18           $3                $8                $23
```

And the dates extend even more.

I want to bring in the amount in the GroupAvgCost column for each group.  Is there a way in SAS or SQL to do this?

I would like something to look like this:

```
Date     Item     Price     Group    AvgCost  
1/1/18   Hat      $5          1         $2
2/1/18   Hat      $5          1         $3
1/1/18   Shirt    $10         2         $8
2/1/18   Shirt    $10         2         $8
1/1/18   Shoes    $30         3         $25
2/1/18   Shoes    $30         3         $23
```

I know one way to do this is to separate the second dataset (AvgCost) into separate files based on their group, add the group number, merge it all on top of each other, then use that file, where all GroupAvgCosts are in one column, to merge into dataset one.

However, given the amount of dates and items, the file would get quite long.  Is there code to merge dataset 1 and dataset two based on date and group number?

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: I am using SAS.

Comment: You're on the right track already with your idea of transposing the second dataset. Generally, working with long datasets is cleaner and easier than working with wide ones. Did you have any problems getting this approach to work?

Comment: I haven’t tried. I assume it could take a while considering the amount of dates and items when I eventually merge. If that’s the best way, I’ll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `proc sql` and `join`:

```
proc sql;
    select d1.*,
           (case when d1.group = 1 then d2.group1avgcost
                 when d1.group = 2 then d2.group2avgcost
                 when d1.group = 3 then d2.group3avgcost
            end) as groupavgcost
    from dataset1 d1 join
         dataset2 d2
         on d1.date = d2.date
```

Comment: This is a neat trick how to perform the transposition right in the PROC SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a `Proc TRANSPOSE` and data step to have the needed shape and extract the group number needed for merging.  You might also need a one or two sorts to ensure the by variables are in order.

A different technique is using a `hash` object to store the averages and lookup the one needed.

For example:

```
data have; 
attrib 
  date format=mmddyy8. informat=mmddyy8.
  item length=$20
  price format=dollar5. informat=dollar5.
  group length=8
;
input
Date     Item    Price    Group; datalines;
1/1/18    Hat      $5        1
2/1/18    Hat      $5        1
1/1/18    Shirt    $10       2
2/1/18    Shirt    $10       2
1/1/18    Shoes    $30       3
2/1/18    Shoes    $30       3
3/1/18    Scarf    $120      5
run;

data haverages;
attrib
  date format=mmddyy8. informat=mmddyy8.
  Group1AvgCost    Group2AvgCost      Group3AvgCost format=dollar5. informat=dollar5.
;
input
Date        Group1AvgCost    Group2AvgCost      Group3AvgCost; datalines;
1/1/18           $2                $8                $25
2/1/18           $3                $8                $23
run;

data want (keep=date item price group avgCost);
  set have;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash lookup();
    lookup.defineKey('date','group');
    lookup.defineData('avgcost');
    lookup.defineDone();
    call missing(avgcost);
    array avg Group1AvgCost    Group2AvgCost      Group3AvgCost;
    do while (not endOfAverages);
      set haverages end=endOfAverages;
      do _n_ = 1 to dim(avg);
        lookup.add(key:date, key:_n_, data:avg[_n_]);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  rc = lookup.find() ;
run;
```